# What is the proper way of distributing a closed source framework that depends on other frameworks/libraries on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, ios-frameworks

I have a closed source framework that depends on other open source project, for sake of discussion let's say Alamofire.

At the moment I am creating a dynamic framework for the closed source code and it uses a 3rd party project linked statically.

The problem I am facing is that if the application also includes the same 3rd party project (for example Alamofire) I have duplicated symbols and it is a bit uncertain which one will be used. I have a lot of messages like:

```
Class <...> is implemented in both <app>.app/Frameworks/<3rd party framework>.framework/<3rd party binary>
and <app>.app/Frameworks/<closed source framework>.framework/<closed source binary> . 
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I have tried to create a static framework but I a link warning:

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework '<3rd party framework>': framework '<3rd party framework>' not found
```

and a link error:

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?